# Why can't I remove the window decorations when using gnome-sceenshot?

Tags: 20.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I can't take screenshots without the windows decorations.
I'm using gnome-screenshot, and according to the manual the optional argument -B should remove the borders.
Here is how my command looks like:

```
gnome-screenshot -w -B -c --file="/tmp/Screenshot_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")"
```

However, my screenshot still includes the windows borders.

I also noticed that in the GUI interactive version, the option to remove window decorations is greyed out.

[Gnome-screenshot GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXv1G.png)

I know that I could probably install other screenshot software and make this work, but I would prefer to understand this behavior and fix this.

I'm in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and using gnome-screenshot 3.36.0

Comment: It looks like this does not work anymore, indeed! The option will be available if you select "grab the current window", but indeed, unchecking the box "Include the window border" doesn't change anything. However, it says "remove border", so we should perhaps not expect it removes the title bar. And borders are practically not there in the default theme.